# Nullpointer Exception While Using Trying to Read Excel in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng

Hi guys i Searched Every Where Solution For But Can't Find. Why Am  Getting Null Pointer Exception For This i Dunno. Please Sort Me This Out. It is Showing as Path is Only Wrong But i Specified it Correctly only.

My Code :

```
package UsingExcel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import com.sun.rowset.internal.Row;

public class Demo 
{

    public void ReadExcel(String filepath,String filename,String Sheetname) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File(filepath); // line 21

        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

        Workbook Mybook = null;

        String FileExtensionnname = filename.substring(filename.indexOf("."));

        if(FileExtensionnname.equals(".xlsx"))
        {
            Mybook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        }
        else if(FileExtensionnname.equals(".xls"))
        {
            Mybook = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
        }

        Sheet filesheet = Mybook.getSheet(Sheetname);

        int rowcount = filesheet.getLastRowNum()-filesheet.getFirstRowNum();

        for(int i=0;i<rowcount+1;i++)
        {
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row row =filesheet.getRow(i);

            for(int j=0;j<row.getLastCellNum();j++)
            {
                System.out.println(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+ "||");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Demo excelfile =  new Demo();

        String filepath = System.getProperty("E:\\Mybook.xlsx");

        excelfile.ReadExcel(filepath, "Mybook.xlsx", "DemoExcel");
        }

}
```

My Error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at UsingExcel.Demo.ReadExcel(Demo.java:21)
    at UsingExcel.Demo.main(Demo.java:61)
```

Hope You Have Understood My Problem, Please Sort This out. But When am Testing a Login Page Using Excel That No Problem Will Be Coming, Now i Try To Print on The 
Console it is Not Working.

Comment: Posting images of code and errors is frowned upon here, because it makes it more difficult for us to help you with your issue.  It is always better to copy and paste the relevant code and/or errors into your question directly.  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you print the value of `filepath` before calling your function? Want to confirm there is a value there.

Comment: Side note: [Stop naming your local variables starting with a capital letter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filepath should just be

`String filepath = "E:\\Mybook.xlsx"`,  don't use `System.getProperty`.

From docs :

> Gets the system property indicated by the specified key

A null is being passed to your method `ReadExcel(...)`, because there is no *System* property defined as *E:\Mybook.xlsx*

Comment: Silly Mistake You are Right, I Changed To String filepath = "E:\\Mybook.xlsx"; and Now it Got Worked . Thanks @Nicholas K